# Java: read from webservice and buffer

Tags: java, web-services, input, output, java-stream

I am looking for an Object. I am quite sure it exists but I don't know its name.

My application receives a JMS message. In the message there are file ids for another system. This system is connected by consuming its webservice. As soon as I receive the message, I will start reading the data from the webservice and write it into some kind of object. This will be like 20000 requests that I will stream into some sort of data strucutre.

In the meanwhile or some time after I finished, a consumer will call a webservice of my application. This will open a stream to the already loaded data and send it as a StreamingResponseBody to the caller. My other thread is still writing data to the streamed object.

The object I am looking for is not a fixed size buffer as I want to read all data even though nobody is interested in the data (yet) and nobody calls the service to download the data.

What object / data structure do you suggest?

I would be able to use a File with an InputStream and an OutputStream but I am not sure if this is the best solution. The performance however won't be the problem as the network speed will limit the read performance anyway.

As my application will be a cloud application, everything is in memory, so persistence is nothing to care about.

Comment: Put in a queue and append to outputstream

Comment: Ya! This sounds good.
However, I would have to add a process management as an empty queue does not mean that there is no more data coming from that other webservice. But I will possibly go for that!
Thanks!